# Picking a random index from an array is always returning me the same index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]



var letter  = letter[Math.round(Math.random()*(quotes.length))]
```

Every time it just returns the last letter, g, not a random one from the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `quotes.length` to `letters.length`

Comment: what is quotes in quotes.length?

Comment: surprised you get anything  ... `var letter  = letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*(letters.length))]` ... so .. `letters[...]` not `letter[...]` .. snt as mentioned above, `letters.length`

Comment: oops, i meant to change quotes to letters

Comment: so, really, the only issue is that you'll occasionally get undefined if you use `Math.round` - which is the only "non-typo" issue in your code

Answer (score 3):

> `(quotes.length)`

What is `quotes`? You want `letters`.

You're doing `var letter  = letter`, but `letter` hasn't been defined yet. Also, when choosing a random element from an array, use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`:

```js
const letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
const letter  = letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length)];
console.log(letter);
```

Comment: i didnt mean to put quotes, that was a typo. i changed it to letters, but its still giving me the same index/letter every time?

Comment: If you want it to work properly, your code should look the same as mine - if it's not working for you, then you're not using the same code as me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to fix a few typos in your code:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
var letter  = letters[Math.round(Math.random()*(letters.length))]
```

Also, you may not want to use `Math.round` since it can cause an out-of-bound array access error. You should try `Math.floor` instead.

Comment: yeah i didnt mean to put the quotes. i changed it to letters. but its still returning the same index every time, the letter "h"??

Comment: @Jesse why did you downvote my answer? I paste it into a Chrome console (with `floor` replacing `round`) and it gives me back random letters. Something else is affecting your code.

Comment: @Jesse - if you get `h` all the time with the above code, your code must be quite different to what you posted in the question

Answer (score -2):

Fix the typos and you should be fine

`var letter  = letters[Math.round(Math.random()*(letters.length))]`

Comment: don't use `Math.round` as mentioned in all other answers that beat you :p